# cakephp: setting routing / pagination options

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I have a rule which looks like this:

```
Router::connect('/Hotels', array('controller' => 'gesamtobjekt', 'action' => 'search', 'cat' => 8));
```

The url looks like this: domain.com/Hotels

My paginations urls like this: domain.com/Hotels/page:2

For language based urls I have a rule like:

```
Router::connect('/:language/:catname/*', array('controller' => 'gesamtobjekt', 'action' => 'search', 'cat' => 8), array(
'catname' => 'Hotels|Hoteles',
'language' => 'eng|spa|fre|rus'
));
```

The url looks like this: domain.com/eng/Hotels

In that case I these params available, so I can be sure, that I am in the right rule.

```
'language' => 'eng',
'catname' => 'Hotels',
'cat' => (int) 8
```

I wonder why my pagination links look like this:

```
domain.com/gesamtobjekt/search/language:eng/page:2
```

What can I do to get a pagination url like domain.com/eng/Hotels/page:2?
What is missing in my rule?

Please advise, thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, May be it will help you.

```
Router::connect('/:language/:catname', array('controller' => 'gesamtobjekt', 'action' => 'search', 'cat' => 8), array(
    'pass' => array('language', 'catname'),
    'catname' => 'Hotels|Hoteles',
    'language' => 'eng|spa|fre|rus'
));
```

Comment: When I try this, I can see in my params:
'pass' => array(
   (int) 0 => 'eng',
   (int) 1 => 'Apartments_Penthouses'
  ),
But there are no changes at the url, it's still domain.com/gesamtobjekt/search/language:eng/page:2

Comment: why don't you try query string parameters for pagination ?
`$this->paginate = array('paramType' => 'querystring')`

Comment: It should be like this `Router::connect('/:language/:catname', array('controller' => 'gesamtobjekt', 'action' => 'search', 'cat' => 8), array(
    'pass' => array('language', 'catname'),
    'catname' => 'Hotels|Hoteles',
    'language' => 'eng|spa|fre|rus'
)); ` I've edited my answer pls check it

Answer (score 0):

funny enough, this works for me:

```
if($this->Session->read('Config.language') != DEFAULT_LANGUAGE){
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'url' => array(
        'controller' => $this->Session->read('Config.language'),
        'action' => $this->params['catname'],
    )
));
}
```